# How to secure a laptop against thieves

Tags: laptop, security, anti-theft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the possible ways for prevention of laptop theft?](https://superuser.com/questions/94229/what-are-the-possible-ways-for-prevention-of-laptop-theft)

Hi !

I'm looking for some **security hw/sw based solution** for my laptop (non standard solution maybe? open the case and add a gsm module.. ). 
Any means that could:

send a location through gsm, gprs, wifi, lan..

so that the thief does not normally know that it's sending something. 
I've read about Intel anti-theft technology which also looks good, but I think that the thief can open the case and change the CPU to another one.. anyways, is this solution available for home end users too ?

I'll appreciate any ideas
Thank you :)

Comment: Desolder and resolder a CPU in a laptop?  How little will the Laptop be worth in resale at that point?

Comment: Alright.. I admit, it's a bit of nonsense..

Answer (score 1):

[LoJack](http://www.absolute.com/en/lojackforlaptops/home.aspx) for Laptops

Comment: Well.. there is some kind of a SW installed directly into bios. What happens if I open the the case and reset cmos with the jumper?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me There isn't software/hardware that is unstoppable.  You can remove the hardware/software of anything.  If it's stored on the hard drive, remove the hard drive.  If it's stored on a chip, remove the chip (or power to the chip, or reset the chip).  If you install a GPS, when I open the laptop, I'm going to see your hack job and remove it.  If your requirement is "hackerproof" the answer is, nothing exists that meets that requirement, nor is it economically feasible, nor necessary.

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me  This will likely be deleted as a duplicate subject anyway:  http://superuser.com/questions/205568/best-way-to-protect-my-laptop-against-theft  http://superuser.com/questions/94229/what-are-the-possible-ways-for-prevention-of-laptop-theft

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me - I'd like to point out, you are thinking like someone playing a game instead of a thief that stole a laptop.  Most thieves that steal a laptop are opportunists (College campuses, Coffee shops, etc..).  An opportunity to bag a laptop pops up and they snag it.  Then they can keep it and use it, or turn it in to quick cash.  For quick cash they aren't going to bother with opening the system.  Just get it on the market for money.  They may take it to a fence, Craigslist it, or pawn it.  Regardless, just because they steal laptops, doesn't mean they know anything about them.

Comment: Alright.. you are definitely right, I was playing with this topic, not taking in mind real behavior of those people..

Comment: If this question will be closed, please add your answer to the mentioned duplicate, so that everyone knows about this solution.. thank you

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me I did not say you were playing with the topic.  I said you were thinking like someone playing a game.  In a hacking game you would steal a laptop and do a bunch of things to it while it was in your possession.  You don't have to consider getting caught with it and going to jail in reality, or economics.  The value of a Laptop decreases over time.  If you are trying to get money, you sell as quickly as possible.  If you aren't, you are an idiot for keeping proof you broke the law.  How smart can that individual be?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me Reality v.s. a hacker game.